# How to get a Node in C without trashing the old linkedlist

Tags: c, linked-list

Hello I am having some troubles when it come to "getting" a node so far my code looks like this...

```
LinklistNode* get_node(LinklistNode* list_head, int index){
LinklistNode* temp = list_head;
if(temp != NULL && index > 0){
    LinklistNode* list_pointer = temp;
    LinklistNode* next_list_pointer = list_pointer ->next;
    while(next_list_pointer->next != NULL && index >0){
        index--;
        if(index == 0) break;
        list_pointer = next_list_pointer;
        next_list_pointer = next_list_pointer ->next;
    }
    temp = list_pointer->next;
    temp->next = NULL;


}
else if(index == 0){
    return temp;
}
return temp;
}
```

... now I've tried to pass it a temp variable that is the exact same but I dont think that is working since they would just share the same memory address, I'm calling it as follow (maybe this will help)

```
LinklistNode* list_head2 = list_head;
list_head2 = get_node(list_head2,2);
print_list(list_head2);
print_list(list_head);
```

And the output from this looks like this

list_head before anything:list: 8 100 7 6 5 3 200 2 1 0 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

list_head2 after you call the method:list: 7

list_head after you have called the method:list: 8 100 7

So my problem is that I'm trashing list_heads values and I don't know how to go about making it so list_heads values and lengths don't change.
Any help at all will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you use the human language that it would be clear what you are trying to do?

Comment: LinklistNode* get_node( LinklistNode* list_head, int index) should return a pointer to the node at index in the list but not delete it. @VladfromMoscow let me know if that clears anything up

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood you correctly you need the following

```
LinklistNode * get_node( LinklistNode *list_head, unsigned int index )
{
    while ( index != 0 && list_head )
    {
        --index;
        list_head = list_head->next;
    }

    return list_head;
}
```

The original list is not changed.

If you need to extract a node then the function can look the following way

```
LinklistNode * get_node( LinklistNode **list_head, unsigned int index )
{
    LinklistNode *prev = NULL, *current = *list_head;

    while ( index != 0 && current )
    {
        --index;
        prev = current; 
        current = current->next;
    }

    if ( prev == NULL )
    {
        if ( current ) *list_head = current->next;
    }
    else if ( current ) 
    {
        prev->next = current->next;
    }

    if ( current ) current->next = NULL;        

    return current;
}
```

If you need a copy of a node then the function can look like

```
LinklistNode * get_node( LinklistNode *list_head, unsigned int index )
{
    LinklistNode *tmp = NULL;

    while ( index != 0 && list_head )
    {
        --index;
        list_head = list_head->next;
    }

    if ( list_head )
    {
        tmp = malloc( sizeof( LinklistNode ) );
        if ( tmp )
        {
            *tmp = *list_head;
            tmp->next = NULL;
        }
    }

    return tmp;
}
```

Comment: The problem is you only want 1 node if you do it this way you get from the index to the end of the list @vladfrommoscow

Answer (score 0):

When you remove the line

```
 temp->next = NULL;
```

then the code can work as you want.

Comment: then I get the result list: 7 6 5 3 200 2 1 0 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

whereas the output should just be the value of the node 7

Comment: Then you must specify what you want. What is a required return value? It can be either a node of list including the pointer to the next value or it can be just a value of the node and the the function should return something like `temp->data`.